# Azure CI pipeline with gradle release - skip tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a requirement where i want to skip all the upcoming tasks if a "Release artifacts" task is run. Release artifact task runs only if one of the variable is set to "true" while running the pipeline.

```
parameters:
  release: $(release)

- task: Bash@3
    displayName: Release artifacts
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.release }}', true))
    inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
            # Write your commands here
            # Steps to release the artifacts ( gradle release plugin)
            gradle release -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true

- task: Bash@3

- task: Bash@3
```

Is there a way to exit/truncate the pipeline with exit code 0 ?  I am looking for a functionality to skip all the upcoming tasks if one of the conditions is true without having to add that check in all the tasks ?

Reason : gradle release will make modification to gradle.properties which will trigger CI again.

Comment: May I know what's the status of this? Does cancel pipeline can do what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can group your tasks in jobs and then use output variable to set that release task was run and use this variable in subsequent job to skip it. Please take look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

```
jobs:
- job: Foo
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "This is job Foo."
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes" #The variable doThing is set to true
    name: DetermineResult
- job: Bar
  dependsOn: Foo
  condition: eq(dependencies.Foo.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes') #map doThing and check if true
  steps:
  - script: echo "Job Foo ran and doThing is true."
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the logic that @Krzysztof mentioned, BUT it seems does not convenient for your scenario since your next process are `steps` rather than `jobs`. This means you need configure `condition` to all next steps to make them skipped.

I have another idea. You can add one `powershell` step after your `Release artifacts` step. The execution condition of this `powershell` step is only previous `Release artifacts` step succeed.

In this powershell step, you can run one api to make the current pipeline cancelled. The nutshell is once the `Release artifacts` step execute succeed, skip all next steps and jobs and cancel current pipeline directly.

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        [String]$project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
        [String]$OrgUri = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"
        $header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
        $pipeline = $OrgUri + $project + "/_apis/build/builds/" + $(Build.BuildId) + “?api-version=6.0-preview.5"
        $Body=@"
        {"status":4}
        "@
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pipeline -Method PATCH -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

[image]

---

With this way, you do not need configure the `condition` to all next tasks or jobs.

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: @SunilS Hope this is the way which you can avoid to make condition check to every next tasks:-)